# Must declare the scalar variable question

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, exec

That is my first post here, need helps:
in a stored procedure I had some following code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_getAvg] (
    @projectId INT
    ,@carrierId INT
    ,@fetchType VARCHAR(20)
    )
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION GetDataSet * *

DECLARE @recAvg FLOAT * *
DECLARE @FACCT VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @carrierAlias AS VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @tmpDate VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(500)

SET @counter = 1

IF @projectId > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @FACCT = FACCT
    FROM projects
    WHERE projectId = @projectId
END

SELECT @carrierAlias = carrierAlias
FROM carriers
WHERE carrierId = @carrierId

SET @sql1 = 'SELECT @recAvg = ISNULL(AVG(cast(FWEIGHT as float)/case when CAST(FPIECES as float) = 0 then 1 else cast(FPIECES as float) end),0) from psorderh where (DATEPART(m, manifestDate) =' + cast(@counter AS VARCHAR(2)) + ') AND (DATEPART(yyyy, manifestDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()))' + CASE 
        WHEN @projectId > 0
            THEN 'AND FACCT = ' + @FACCT
        ELSE ''
        END + CASE 
        WHEN @carrierId > 0
            THEN 'and FCARRIER=' + @carrierAlias
        ELSE ''
        END

EXEC (@sql1)

PRINT @recAvg
```

......

I got this error message:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@recAvg".

where I did wrong?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Mostly to eliminate all the SQL injection and string handling issues, and remove things unused:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_getAvg]
    @projectId INT
    ,@carrierId INT
    ,@fetchType VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN    
  DECLARE @recAvg FLOAT,
          @FACCT VARCHAR(20),
          @counter INT = 1,
          @carrierAlias VARCHAR(20),
          @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  IF @projectId > 0
  BEGIN
    SELECT @FACCT = FACCT FROM projects WHERE projectId = @projectId;
  END

  SELECT @carrierAlias = carrierAlias FROM carriers WHERE carrierId = @carrierId;

  SET @sql = N'SELECT @recAvg = ISNULL(AVG(cast(FWEIGHT as float)/case 
      when CAST(FPIECES as float) = 0 then 1 else cast(FPIECES as float) end),0) 
      from psorderh where DATEPART(MONTH, manifestDate) = @counter 
        AND DATEPART(YEAR, manifestDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())' 
    + CASE WHEN @projectId > 0 THEN N' AND FACCT = @FACCT' ELSE N'' END 
    + CASE WHEN @carrierId > 0 THEN N' AND FCARRIER = @carrierAlias' ELSE N'' END;

    DECLARE @params nvarchar(max) 
      = N'@counter int,@FACCT varchar(20),@carrierAlias varchar(20),@recAvg float OUTPUT';

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, @params, @counter, @FACCT, @carrierAlias, @recAvg OUTPUT;

    PRINT @recAvg;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are declaring the `DECLARE @recAvg FLOAT * *` outside the dynamic SQL.

you should do

`SET @sql1 = 'DECLARE @recAvg FLOAT ; SELECT @recAvg ....`

Also when in doubt, always use print before running the EXEC or sp_executesql.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using sp_executesql and then declaring the parameter and outputting the desired variable.  Please see below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_getAvg] (
    @projectId INT
    ,@carrierId INT
    ,@fetchType VARCHAR(20)
    )
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION GetDataSet * *

DECLARE @recAvg FLOAT * *
DECLARE @FACCT VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @carrierAlias AS VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @tmpDate VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @sqlparam VARCHAR(500)

SET @counter = 1

IF @projectId > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @FACCT = FACCT
    FROM projects
    WHERE projectId = @projectId
END

SELECT @carrierAlias = carrierAlias
FROM carriers
WHERE carrierId = @carrierId

SET @sqlparam = '@recAvg FLOAT OUTPUT'

SET @sql1 = 'SET @recAvg = (SELECT ISNULL(AVG(cast(FWEIGHT as float)/case when CAST(FPIECES as float) = 0 then 1 else cast(FPIECES as float) end),0) from psorderh where (DATEPART(m, manifestDate) =' + cast(@counter AS VARCHAR(2)) + ') AND (DATEPART(yyyy, manifestDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()))' + CASE 
        WHEN @projectId > 0
            THEN 'AND FACCT = ' + @FACCT
        ELSE ''
        END + CASE 
        WHEN @carrierId > 0
            THEN 'and FCARRIER=' + @carrierAlias
        ELSE ''
        END + ')'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql1, @sqlparam, @recAVG OUT

PRINT @recAvg
```